# How to enqueue each element in a vector of unique pointers? (C++)

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, queue, smart-pointers

I'm trying to push each element of a vector of unique pointers into a queue, but for some reason my code won't compile.

The error I'm getting is: `error: use of deleted function ‘std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>::unique_ptr(const std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>&) [with _Tp = Foo; _Dp = std::default_delete<Foo>]’`.

Since I'm moving the vector of unique pointers into the `enqueue` function, and again moving each element into `queue_`, I'm not sure why this isn't working.

```
#include <memory>
#include <vector>
#include <queue>

class Foo {};

class Bar {
  
 public:
  template<typename Container>
  void enqueue(Container c) {
    for (const auto &e : c) {
      queue_.push(std::move(e));
    }
  };
  
 private:
  std::queue<std::unique_ptr<Foo>> queue_;
};

int main() {

  Bar bar;

  std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Foo>> c;
  c.push_back(std::make_unique<Foo>());

  bar.enqueue(std::move(c)); // this line is causing problem

};
```

Comment: `const auto &e`, `std::move(e)`: moving const element does copy...

Comment: Ah, thank you. I didn't know that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an extra `const` which avoid the move and do a (deleted) copy instead:

Remove it and use:

```
for (auto &e : c) {
    queue_.push(std::move(e));
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7514b9a21ccada4e)

Comment: Maybe even better `for (auto &&e : c)`